# Using Excel To Read From Access Without MS Access Installed On Computer 

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I have written code that joins two table in access, using criteria supplied from drop down lists in Excel and then returns the data to a specific location on the spreadsheet (titles already on the sheet).

This works fine on my box and others with MS Access on the machine, but the purpose of writing this was to give people (associates) that don't have MS Access on their machines (which is most of them) to be able to do simple queries to the database.

When we try to run this on a machine without MS Access, we are getting the error message

> "Compile Error: Can't find project or library."

Since this works fine on any machine so far that has Access, but not the others I am wondering if this is not possible without the actual Access software. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to get on a machine without MSAccess and found out that the compile errors had nothing to do with the SQL, but was happening with other code.  As it turns out I had had a reference to "MicroSoft Access 10.0 Object Library" set in the references and since the boxes we tried it on with Access worked since it only has the library if you have Access installed.  Also turns out that reference is not needed to do the query to the database, and when that reference was eliminated it worked fine on boxes without Access.  As usual the errors are in the least likely place you would think.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use ADO and the "jet" provider. This will allow you to query an access database without having access installed

```
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open "c:/webdata/northwind.mdb"

set objRecordset=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
objRecordset.activeconnection = conn
objRecordset.source = "select * from table where field1 = 'asdf'"
objRecordset.open

'do you work here

objRecordset.close
conn.close
```

Comment: also add 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library' and 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library'.